# Finding conditional expectation by definition

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-expectation

> **Problem:** Let $X_1,X_2,\ldots \sim  \text{Exp}(1)$. Denote $S_n=\sum_{k=1}^nX_k$, $N(x)=\inf\{ n>0\mid S_n>x\}$, $m=\mathbb{E}[N(x)]$.
> Prove by definition,
> $$\mathbb{E}[N(x)\mid X_1]=
> \begin{cases}
> m(x-X_1)+1 &,\text{ if } X_1\le x\\
> 1 &,\text{ if } X_1>x 
> \end{cases}=:g(x)$$

I'm taking a course in probability and we just defined conditional expectation.
intuitive I understand why this is equal but I'm having trouble proving it by definition.

My approach:

Define $A=\{{X_1<s}\}$ an and from The π- theorem it is enough to show for all s, $\mathbb{E}[N(x)*1_A ]=\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[N(x)|X_1]*1_A]$.

 $s\le t:$
 $\mathbb{E}[N(t)*1_A]=\mathbb{E}[N(t)*1_{X_1<s}]=\sum_{k=0}^\infty k\mathbb{P}(N(t)=k,\ X_1<s)$.
 We'll notice that $$\mathbb{P}(N(t)=k,\ X_1<s)=\mathbb{P}(\forall m\le k:\ S_m<t,\ S_k\ge t,\ X_1<s)$$
$$=\mathbb{P}(\forall m\le k:\ X_2+...+X_m<t-X_1,\ X_2+...+X_k\ge t-X_1,\ X_1<s)$$
$$=\mathbb{P}(N(t-X_1)+1=k,X_1<s)$$
And so $$\mathbb{E}[N(t)*1_A]=\mathbb{E}[N(t)*1_{X_1<s}]=\sum_{k=0}^\infty k\mathbb{P}(N(t)=k,\ X_1<s)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty k\mathbb{P}(N(t-X_1)+1=k,X_1<s)=\mathbb{E}[(1+N(t-X_1))1_{X_1<s}]$$

$s> t$: 
I tried instead of working with $\{X_1<s\}$ to work with $\{X_1\ge s\}$
$$\mathbb{E}[N(x)*1_{X_1<s} ]=\mathbb{E}[N(x)*(1-1_{X_1\ge s})]=\mathbb{E}[N(x)]-\mathbb{E}[N(x)*1_{X_1\ge s})]=\mathbb{E}[N(x)]-\mathbb{P}(X_1\ge s)$$
$$\mathbb{E}[g(x)1_{X_1< s}]=\mathbb{E}[g(x)]-\mathbb{P}(X_1\ge s)$$

But then I get that I need to prove $\mathbb{E}[N(x)]=\mathbb{E}[g(x)]$.  Which is the original claim I want to prove.

How do I continoue from here?

Thank you

Comment: I know noticed I havn't used the fact that $X_i \sim exp(1)$. Even at s<t, so I'm guessing I have a mistake there some where.